# SSIS Package occasionally does not execute from SQL Job

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS job that runs every 15 minutes.  One of over 2 dozen that run on regular intervals throughout the day.  Occasionally, they fail, the job fails before ever getting to the point where it executes the SSIS package.  You can see below.  I've attached an image of the report ssis execution.  3PM today it failed, going into the SSIS Report Execution, no entry was there for 3PM.

How do I debug this?  It seems to happen in spurts.  When 1 fails, all of a sudden 5 will fail at the same interval.  They may pick up and run fine the next time, they may fail again.

JOB RUN:    'Production_365_To_DW_Full_Sync' was run on 9/9/2020 at 3:00:00 PM
DURATION:   0 hours, 0 minutes, 20 seconds
STATUS:     Failed
MESSAGES:   The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 29 (Every 30 Minutes).  The last step to run was step 1 (Execute SSIS).

[image: Report Execution Log]

Comment: You need to implement some error reporting (Event Handling) in your SSIS job.  There are a bunch of different ways to do that.  For me, personally, I make use of Event Handling and write out the error message to an email that gets sent to me any time the SSIS job fails.  SQL Agent doesn't have access to the error within the SSIS job.  It only reports failure.  Not the actual reason.

Comment: Devlin, I think the issue is that the package is failing to start. Otherwise, if it started but failed during the execution phase, we'd see it here. What does the Operations view have to say `SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operations AS O WHERE O.created_time > '2020-09-09T14:59:00' AND O.created_time < '2020-09-09T15:01:00'`

Comment: thanks Bill, yes, the package isn't getting executed at all.  I went back to 1PM to get results and last run was at 2pm.  There are 2 rows every 15 minutes because 2 packages exist in this SSIS object.  SELECT top 10 * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operations AS O WHERE O.created_time > '2020-09-09 13:00 -04:00' AND O.created_time < '2020-09-09 15:01 -03:01' and object_name = '365 To DW Full Sync' order by created_time desc

Comment: 1189979 200 2020-09-09 14:00:09.7549327 -04:00 20 26 365 To DW Full Sync 7 2020-09-09 14:00:10.4893607 -04:00 2020-09-09 14:00:34.5848793 -04:00 0x010500000000000515000000FE26C64820DD73398A5A4160033C0000 29100 NULL   this is the last one .. i don't know how to post pictures in comments here on stack exchange .. not sure if i can